# is(':hover') is not working properly in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a drawer menu that opens the bottom part of the navigation menu when I hover on a list item on the upper part of the menu.

I want to keep the bottom menu open when you move the mouse from the list item on the upper part to the menu but make it disappear if you move the mouse elsewhere.

So, I gave the menu an ID and control the movement with Jquery.

and I wrote something like this.

```
  $('.headerNavigationGroupList').mouseleave(() => {
    if ($('#navMenu').is(':hover')) {
      //if navMenu is hovered, do nothing//
      return
    }else {
        //else close the menu//
      const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(
        'headerBottom__list-group',
      )
      closeMenu(elements)
    }
  })
```

this works perfectly in googleChrome, but it does not work in IE11.

I did console.log $('#navMenu').is(':hover') and it seemed that IE11 was not able to check if the nav menu is hovered.

next, I changed my code like this

```
$('#navMenu:hover').length > 0
```

however, nothing changed. Console Log still said 0, even though it said 1 on google chrome.

I have no idea why this only happens with IE. Does anyone have an idea why?

the bottom part of dom looks like this

```
<div class="headerBottom" id="navMenu">
  <div class="headerBottomInner">
    <div class="headerBottom__list-group">
      <ul class="headerBottom__list-group__list">
        <li class="is-about headerBottom__list-group__list__item">
        //stuff//
         </li>

      </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For one thing, there is no support for "fat arrow" functions in IE11. Write "full" functions instead. You should be writing full functions for jQuery event handlers anyway, as only those will give you correct `this` handling.

Comment: I tried that but it did not work  and im using typescript and my eslint gives an error when i do yarn run build

Comment: Can you get `:hover` to work with `document.querySelectorAll` on IE11?  (That's a vanilla JS equivalent to what jQuery does.)

Comment: I just tried `document.queryselectorAll(":hover")` on IE11, and it worked, but it didn't necessarily correspond to the element appearing hovered with the dev tools open.  That is, right click the element and choose "inspect element"->the element is styled as though hovered but doesn't count as hovered for console commands.  ACTUALLY hover it, and it does count as hovered for console commands.

Comment: I just tried document.querySelector(".headerBottom__list-group__list:hover"), and it returned null, even though i got the result on chrome
it seems like this is the cause

Answer (score 1):

As the comments, IE does not support lambda. And do not keep some distance between the element `headerNavigationGroupList` and the element `navMenu`. When the mouse leaves the `headerNavigationGroupList`, the element `navMenu` has been hidden.

You can follow the alternative example.

1. Make no distance between `headerNavigationGroupList` and `navMenu`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="headerNavigationGroupList">
        headerNavigationGroupList
    
        <div class="headerBottom" id="navMenu">
            <div class="headerBottomInner">
                <div class="headerBottom__list-group">
                    <ul class="headerBottom__list-group__list">
                        <li class="is-about headerBottom__list-group__list__item">
                            //stuff//
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(
            'headerBottom__list-group')[0].style.cssText = 'display:none'
        $('.headerNavigationGroupList').mouseleave(function () {
               
            if ($('#navMenu').is(':hover')) {
                //if navMenu is hovered, do nothing//
                return
            } else {
                //else close the menu//
                const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(
                    'headerBottom__list-group'
                )[0]
                closeMenu(elements)
            }
        })
        $('.headerNavigationGroupList').mouseenter(function () {
            const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(
                'headerBottom__list-group'
            )[0].style.cssText = 'display:block'
        })
    })
    function closeMenu(e) {
        e.style.cssText = 'display:none'
    }
</script>

</html>
```

2. Change `is(':hover')` to `$('#navMenu').hover()`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="headerNavigationGroupList">
        headerNavigationGroupList
    </div>
        <div class="headerBottom" id="navMenu">
            <div class="headerBottomInner">
                <div class="headerBottom__list-group">
                    <ul class="headerBottom__list-group__list">
                        <li class="is-about headerBottom__list-group__list__item">
                            //stuff//
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js""></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(
            'headerBottom__list-group')[0].style.cssText = 'display:none'
        $('.headerNavigationGroupList').mouseleave(function () {
                $('#navMenu').hover(function(){
                    
                },
                function(){
                    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(
                        'headerBottom__list-group'
                    )[0]
                    closeMenu(elements)
                })
           
        })
        $('.headerNavigationGroupList').mouseenter(function () {
            const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(
                'headerBottom__list-group'
            )[0].style.cssText = 'display:block'
        })
    })
    function closeMenu(e) {
        e.style.cssText = 'display:none'
    }
</script>

</html>
```